# New/create action in nested routes is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**UPDATE TO QUESTION**

I think I know where the problem is: I am not passing the user to question. However I am not sure how to do so.
This is for sure the problem because if I write in

**view/questions/new.html.erb**:

```
 <%= f.association :user, label: "Which user is creating it?",
:as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user.id }  %>
```

It works. However this is not the best way to pass the user. BUT I do not know how to do it.

**END UPDATE**

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am building a website where a user can create a project. Each project contains several papers. Each paper can be reviewed by answering several question.

I have four models (User, Project, Paper, Questions).

I am stuck in the `new/create` action for submitting the answers to a paper via a simple_form_for (**view/questions/new.html.erb**). Basically, a simple_form to answer a the questions of the model `Question`.
Both `paper.id` and `project.id` are successfully passed but the new creation of a review does not occur. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**view/questions/new.html.erb**

```
  <div class="container">
  <h4>You are reviewing the questions for paper paper:</h4>

    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

        <%= simple_form_for [@project, @paper, @question] do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :question_1, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"], label: "Question 1" %>
        <%= f.input :question_2, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"], label: "Question 2" %>
        <%= f.input :question_3, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"], label: "Question 3" %>

        <div class="form-actions">
          <%= f.button :submit, "Send your review" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**questions_controllers.rb**

```
  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @paper = Paper.find(params[:paper_id])
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    @question.paper = Paper.find(params[:paper_id])
    @question.project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    if @question.save
      redirect_to projects_path
    else
      render :new
    end
```

**user.rb - Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :projects
  has_many :questions
end
```

**project.rb - Model**

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :papers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions
```

**paper.rb - Model**

```
class Paper < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :questions
  has_one_attached :paper_pdf
end
```

**question.rb - Model**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :paper
  belongs_to :project
end
```

**route.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects do
    resources :papers do
      resources :questions
    end
  end
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'pages#home'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

**rails routes output on terminal**

[image: Rails routes]

Comment: show me @question.errors.messages

Comment: I have never used .errors.messages. Where am I supposed to use it? Many thanks

Comment: I noticed you have `resources :questions` twice in your routes. Why is that?

Comment: No, it was a mistake. Thanks! I removed it but I still get a mistake: `NoMethodError in Questions#create` and `undefined method questions_path'`. The `_path` of my `Question#create` is `project_paper_questions`.

Comment: can you please post up your rails routes ?

Comment: Thanks! I added them via an image on the original post.

Comment: You should show your models, but I guess you can do something like `@question = current_user.questions.new(question_params)`

Comment: I just added the four models I have: User, Project, Paper, Question